# Crontab Formatting - every 15 minutes

Tags: unix, cron

I'm trying to get a simple crontab job to run every 15 minutes and am having trouble deciding how to format the timing.

What I've been putting down is the following:

```
15 * * * * ------------------------
```

I'm pretty sure this just runs the first 15 minutes of every hour.

I think that crontab allows users to specify exact times to run, namely:

```
0, 15,30,45 * * * * -------------------------
```

But if I wanted to run the crontab every 15 minutes from the moment I start it, (which may not necessarily be on a value divisible by 15), how would I go about formatting that/is that possible?

Comment: What is "the moment you start it"? When you have finished `crontab -e`? When you're system has booted?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Crontab doesn't remember what time you "started" (presumably the time you executed the `crontab -e` or `crontab filename` command).

If you want to run the job every 15 minutes starting from an arbitrary time, you'll have to specify that time. This:

```
7-59/15 * * * * command
```

will run at 7, 22, 37, and 52 minutes after each hour. That's assuming you're running Vixie cron, which is the most common implementation. For better portability, you can use:

```
7,22,37,52 * * * * command
```

And remember that you can't have spaces within any of the first 5 fields; `0, 15,30,45`, as you had in your question, is invalid.

Comment: For clarity - crond runs once a minute.   That is the daemon that runs crontab  items for you.  If you do NOT use crontab to edit the crontab file, crond will not see the changes.  If you use crontab, "now" is the first execution of crond after you save the file.

Comment: @jimmcnamara: If you use something other than `crontab` to edit the crontab file -- well, just don't do that. Editing the file directly requires (a) knowing where it is, and (b) using root access. Don't use root access for *anything* unless it's actually necessary and you know just what you're doing.

Comment: `7/15` as minute is not supported on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. `*/15` works

Comment: You're right. I've updated the specification, and I'm testing it now (of course it will take a while to produce results).

Comment: I know what the problem is, A step value, like `/15` has to be associated with a range, not just a single value. That's why `7/15` is invalid, but `7-59/15` is ok. (My test triggered at 22 minutes after the hour, which is what I expected; I'll leave it running for a while.)

Answer (score 43):

You would format the crontab like this to get it to run every 15 minutes.

`*/15 * * * * [path/to/script]`

Comment: The most common `crontab` implementation does support that syntax. If you need maximum portability, change `*/15` to `0,15,30,45`.

Answer (score 1):

`0,15,30,45` for 15 minutes is incorrect.

The better and simply way is `*/15 * * * *` for 15 minutes.

```
5 minutes
*/5 * * * *

15 minutes
*/15 * * * *

30 minutes
*/30 * * * *

60 minutes
0 * * * *

1 day
0 0 * * *
```

Comment: Would be good to specify WHY `0,15,30,45` is incorrect.