# Need program to keep restarting itself after a certain amount of time

Tags: python, loops, time

I need this program to restart after15 minutes and repeat its process over again. I need it to be on a timer so example it starts ever 15 minutes dynamically without any user imput it will just reset and start over and restart in the Python shell.

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
import time
import random
from auth import (
    consumer_key,
    consumer_secret,
    access_token,
    access_token_secret
)

twitter = Twython(
    consumer_key,
    consumer_secret,
    access_token,
    access_token_secret
)
start_time = time.time()
search_results = twitter.search(q="lol", count=100)
try:
    for tweet in search_results["statuses"]:
        try:
            st= tweet["entities"]["user_mentions"]
            if st != []:
                screen_name = st[0]["screen_name"]
                twitter.create_friendship(screen_name = st[0]["screen_name"])
                twitter.retweet(id = tweet["id_str"])

                for name in bot_detectors:
                    if name == screen_name:
                        try:
                            twitter.destroy_friendship(screen_name = st[0]["screen_name"])
                            twitter.destroy_status(id = tweet["id_str"])
                            twitter.create_block(screen_name=name)

                        except TwythonError as e:
                            print (e)
```

Comment: Why don't you consider something like `cron` or `Windows Scheduler`? Those are more flexible and you can just focus on the business logic?

Comment: For more details on cron, which you absolutely should use instead of relying on python timers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033542/crontab-formatting-every-15-minutes

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have very specific requirements, it is always better to put the logic of restarting the script outside the script itself:

- the script is simpler to write and test  (one functionality less)
- if (for any reason including program bugs) the script crashes it will be automatically restarted on next launch time
- if (for any reason including program bugs) the script uses more and more resources in long runs, it will release everithing on each stop and will do a fresh start on each new run
- [separation of concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is generaly seen as one of the *best practices*

On Unix-like systems, you will find cron and crontab, on Windows the task scheduler, so it already exists out of the box without any development.