# Cron running every minute, instead of running every 15

Tags: cron, cron-task

I wish to run the following cron every 15 minutes, but for some reason it tries running the command every minute, which then forces the server to run very slow as it starts completing multiple backups at once as it takes about 5 minutes per backup.

Not a final solution, I was testing with cron to see if the schedule system would work well for this.

```
*15 * * * *  /var/nextcloudbackup/runbackup.sh
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crontab Formatting - every 15 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033542/crontab-formatting-every-15-minutes)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to run every 15 minutes, you need `*/15` (or `0,15,30,45`), not `*15`.

More fundamentally, though, you should consider having your backup process prevent duplicate simultaneous executions using a lock file or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula: `*/15 * * * *`. I also built [this tool](https://crontab.cronhub.io/) which helps you and anyone to easily generate cron schedules.